# MySQL Partition By DATEDIFF

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a table with the **ReferenceDate** field. I intend to partition it using this field as follows:

- partition_0: Values more than 1 year old;
- partition_1: Values older than 6 months;
- partition_2: Values older than 3 months;
- partition_3: Values for the last 3 months;

For this I tried the following script to change the table:

```
ALTER TABLE `MyTable`
        PARTITION BY RANGE (DATEDIFF(NOW(), `ReferenceDate`)) 
        (
            PARTITION p0_historic_data VALUES LESS THAN (90),
            PARTITION p1_intermediary_data VALUES LESS THAN (180),
            PARTITION p2_intermediary_data VALUES LESS THAN (365),
            PARTITION p3_current_data VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE 
        );
```

However, I believe that I cannot use the Now () function, in the partitioning clause, something I was able to do was use TO_DATE, but it doesn't give me the return I need, with DIFF I have the value of the difference of the current date and ReferenceDate , TO_DATE returns the value in days from year 0 to the current date.

I would like to know if there is really no way to use DIFF, or if there is any alternative in that sense.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, since it would have to update all the partitions continuously as the current time changes.

Comment: I understand, the doubt was more in that sense, that is, to know if there is any way to do this dynamically ...@Barmar

Comment: I don't think so. It would have to repartition at least every day, and possibly more frequently if `ReferenceDate` is a `DATETIME` rather than `DATE` (since the date difference depends on the current time of day).

Answer (score 1):

A `PARTITIONed` table is one where some of the rows are permanently put in one 'sub-table' or another, based on the instructions in `PARTITION BY ...`.

So, it is flatly not possible.  To implement such, MySQL would have to move rows from one partition to another, *even when you are not touching the table*.

Even if it were possible, it might not provide any performance improvement.  After all, you can have something like this:

```
WHERE ReferenceDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 180 DAY
  AND ReferenceDate  < NOW() - INTERVAL  90 DAY
```

Then, if you also have

```
  AND CustomerId = 123
```

then this index would be excellent for finding the desired rows:

```
INDEX(CustomerId, ReferenceDate)
```

*That does not need `PARTITIONing`*.